# Why does Firefox and Chrome behave differently when using U+3002 with `word-break: keep-all`?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I entered the following sentence in `textarea` using Japanese.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

textarea {
  width: 5em;
  height: 10em;
  word-break: keep-all;
}
```

```html
<textarea>あいうえお。かきくけこ</textarea>
```

This is such an image in Firefox, and the sentence follows immediately after the U+3002 (。).

[image: Firefox Result]

However, in Chrome, a line break is made immediately after U+3002 (。).

[image: Chrome Result]

According to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break#Values), `keep-all` does not allow CJK text breaks.

> `keep-all`
>
> Word breaks should not be used for Chinese/Japanese/Korean (CJK) text. Non-CJK text behavior is the same as for normal.

So I thought Chrome was working differently than the spec. How do I get Chrome's text breaks to work like Firefox?

---

OS and Browser Details

- Windows 10
- Firefox Developer Edition 67.0b1
- Google Chrome 72.0.3626.121

Answer (score 0):

What happens here in Chrome is that <textarea> have a special `overflow-wrap` value, which is set to `break-word`. 
This means that when you add your own `word-break: keep-all` on this, the two values will conflict.

Chrome seems to first honor the `word-break` rule, while Firefox ignores it, as demonstrated here:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

textarea {
  width: 5em;
  height: 10em;
  word-break: keep-all;
  overflow-wrap: normal;
}
```

```html
<textarea>あいうえお。かきくけこ</textarea>
```

And then Chrome applies the `overflow-wrap` on this result, which indeed double breaks your sentence.

So the really strange thing here, is why does Chrome refuse to break **before** any dot character even with `word-break: break-all`...

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

textarea {
  width: 1em;
  height: 46em;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<textarea>あいうえお。かきくけこ푸바.밫foobar.baz..............</textarea>
```

And this, not only in <textarea>

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.test {
  width: 1em;
  height: 46em;
  word-break: break-all;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">あいうえお。かきくけこ푸바.밫foobar.baz..............</div>
```

Unfortunately, I didn't found a way to circumvent this behavior...